Kubuntu 24.04 managing USB devices power when computer sleeps or shutdown
Kubuntu 24.04 managing USB devices power when computer sleeps or shutdown. My USB devices (mouse and keyboard) are powered on even after I shutdown my PC.
They also get powered when the PC is in sleep mode.
I got Windows installed on this computer and after I shutdown the keyboard and mouse are not powered. When I put my PC into sleep mode from Windows they are still powered (I can wake my PC up by keyboard key hit) but the lights are disabled on both mouse and keyboard.
How can I achieve the same state on Kubuntu 24.04? Or at least how to make my PC not powering these USB devices after shutdown?
